# What will be the probability that all the 4 papers are checked by exactly 2 teachers?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the papers of 4 students can be checked by 7 teachers, then What will be the probability that all the 4 papers are checked by exactly 2 teachers?

I am unable to get this question.

Comment: As I read this question, there are four papers, and they are each given to a random teacher form among the seven available. They are asking what the probability is that there are only two teachers who ever get to correct a paper (and five who are left without anything to do).

Comment: @Arthur I got that. But No idea how to start ?

Comment: Do you know the probability that they're all checked by the _same_ teacher, for instance?

Comment: Possible solution idea. First see how many pairs of two teachers you can make. Then find the probability that each of the papers is graded by somebody in that pair.  Finally, for the denominator, figure out how many ways the papers can be graded with no restrictions. Edit(you don't have to worry about a denominator if you were using probabilities instead of counts for the first part)

Comment: @Arthur, I guess $1/7^3$

Comment: @Garrick Not bad. Now, for two teachers, the idea is more or less the same. It's just a bit mroe convoluted.

Comment: @Arthur, I am getting $(7/7)(6/7)(2/7)(2/7)$. Please check ?

Answer (score 1):

I find it a useful ploy to convert a problem to a familiar type:

Let us convert this into throwing a $7$ faced die $4$ times, and getting exactly $2$ faces

Then favorable ways can be computed as :

[ Choose faces to come up ] $\times$ [ Permute ]

There are two possibilities:

$3-1\;of\;a\;kind: [\binom71\binom61] \times [\frac{4!}{3!1!}]$

$2-2\;of\;a\;kind: [ \binom72] \times [\frac{4!}{2!2!}]$

Add up to get favorable ways, and divide by $7^4$ to get the final result

This mightn't be the most direct way, but compensates by the assurance of familiarity !

---

**Added**

The direct way, after choosing $2$ teachers, would be to use probabilities directly, and use inclusion-exclusion, viz $\binom72[(\frac27)^4 - \binom21(\frac17)^4]$

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I found the problem almost trivial. The first paper goes to some teacher with probability 7/7, and only the teacher choices for the second, third and fourth papers matter.  One or more must go to (only one) someone else. For the case where the second goes to someone else (6/7 of the time) the third and fourth must go to one of the -now established - teacher pair (2/7 of the time for each paper). The probability of that sequence happening is 6*2*2/(7*7*7). if the first two papers go to the same teacher and the third to someone else, the probability of the sequence is 1*6*2/(7*7*7). The last case is the first three going to one teacher, and the last to someone else, with probability 1*1*6/(7*7*7). The answer is

(6*2*2+1*6*2+1*1*6)/(7*7*7).=6/49=0.12245 or 12.245%